# Vector Iterator not decrementable?

Tags: c++, vector

Can some one shed some light on why this code snipit will run though the loop once but then give an assertion failure Expression: vector iterator not decrementable?

```
for (auto an = a.rbegin(); an != a.rend(); ++an, indexA--) //first number 
{
        for (auto bn = b.rbegin(); bn != b.rend(); ++bn) //second number
        {
            if (*an - *bn >= 0)
            {
                returnVal.push_back(*an - *bn);
                a.pop_back();
                b.pop_back();
            }
            else
            {
                brrow = *an + 10;
                a.at(indexA - 1) = a.at(indexA - 1) - 1; // remove 1 from the spot ahead of current digit
                returnVal.push_back(brrow - *bn);
                a.pop_back();
                b.pop_back();
            }
        }   
}
```

Comment: You are modifying the contents of the `vector` during the iteration! This makes the iterators invalid!

Comment: Is there a way that I can revaladate the iterator when I pop_back?

Comment: Nope! That's just not possible AFAIK.

Comment: Uh... actually pop_back() only invalidates end and back.  other iterators should still be valid.

Comment: @SingleNegationElimination so pop_back()  does not invalidate rend and rback?

Comment: Invalidating `end()` invalidates `rbegin()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems you want to move through both iterator ranges in tandem - that only needs one `for` loop, like this:

```
auto an = a.rbegin();
for (auto bn = b.rbegin();
     an != a.rend() && bn != b.rend();
     ++an, ++bn, indexA--)
    if (*an - *bn >= 0)
        returnVal.push_back(*an - *bn);
    else
    {
        brrow = *an + 10;
        --(a.at(indexA - 1)); // remove 1 from the spot ahead of current digit
                              // shouldn't you check for rend() first????
        returnVal.push_back(brrow - *bn);
    }
```

Note that both iterators can be declared as `for`-loop local *if* you know they'll be of the exact same type:

```
for (auto an = a.rbegin(), bn = b.rbegin(); ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I have been trying to rack my head for a O(n) solution for a bit. for some reason my mind got stuck on "I have 2 vectors I need 2 loops" This does get rid of the errors that I have.

Answer (score 0):

pop_back() will make your iterator invalid.

Following explains more in detail ([Does pop_back() really invalidate *all* iterators on an std::vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62340/does-pop-back-really-invalidate-all-iterators-on-an-stdvector)):

> *Here is your answer, directly from The Holy Standard:*
>
> **23.2.4.2** A vector satisfies all of the requirements of a container and of a reversible container (given in two tables in 23.1) and of a
> sequence, including most of the optional sequence requirements
> (23.1.1).
>
> **23.1.1.12** Table 68 expressiona.**pop_back()** return typevoid operational semanticsa.**erase(--a.end())** containervector, list, deque
>
> *Notice that
> a.pop_back is equivalent to a.erase(--a.end()). Looking at vector's
> specifics on erase:*
>
> **23.2.4.3.3** - iterator erase(iterator position) - effects - **Invalidates all the iterators and references after the point of the erase**
>
> *Therefore, once you call pop_back, any iterators to the previously
> final element (which now no longer exists) are invalidated.*

---

More information: FAQ "Iterator invalidation rules":
[Iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?